# json-extract sqlite format

Tags: sqlite, json-extract

I used the following command 
`SELECT json_extract(data,'$.address') FROM data;`

and output as CSV file.

Output in CSV file is

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WG4Gy.png)

Field (column) in CSV file is saved as 2 lines for 1 field (column).

Eg-

"71 CHOA CHU KANG LOOP

NORTHVALE"

How could I save field(column) as 1 line ?

That is I don't want to include new line character in filed(column).

Eg-

"71 CHOA CHU KANG LOOP NORTHVALE"

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace the new line character:

```
select replace(json_extract(data,'$.address'), char(10), '') from data;
```

This will catch the newline character (`'\n'`). If you want `'\r'` and `'\r\n'` too:

```
select replace(
    replace(json_extract(data,'$.address'), char(10), ''), 
    char(13),
    ''
) from data;
```

Comment: Thanks so much, How could I replace **comma** (,) ?

Comment: @kkk: welcome; just extend the expression with more nested `replace()`, as showned in my second query.

Comment: Thanks GMB, got it, I need to use **char(44)**

Comment: ,how could I remove double quote and \n at above ? The result I'd like to be 71 CHOA CHU KANG LOOP NORTHVALE without double quote and \n